# how to count android gcm payload length

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, payload

In the android GCM document, it is said the payload has a limit of 4096 bytes.

However, I found that I can send a payload with 16834 byes.

Did I make a mistake? I computed the length as follows:

---

```
Map<Object, Object> jsonRequest = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
setJsonField(jsonRequest, GCMConstants.PARAM_TIME_TO_LIVE, message.getTimeToLive());
setJsonField(jsonRequest, GCMConstants.PARAM_COLLAPSE_KEY, message.getCollapseKey()); 
setJsonField(jsonRequest, GCMConstants.PARAM_DELAY_WHILE_IDLE, message.isDelayWhileIdle());
jsonRequest.put(GCMConstants.JSON_REGISTRATION_IDS, registrationIds); 
Map<String, Object> payload = message.getData(); 
if (!payload.isEmpty()) { 
    jsonRequest.put(GCMConstants.JSON_PAYLOAD, payload);
}  
String requestBody = gson.toJson(jsonRequest); 
System.out.println(requestBody.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
```

---

Furthermore, what's the response from GCM if the payload is too long?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the payload is too big, you'll get "MessageTooBig" in the error message.
The part of the payload that must not exceed 4096 is all the custom keys and values in the payload. You don't count the registration ids and you don't count predefined keys such as time to live and collapse key.
By the way, I found out that even though the documentation says the payload must not exceed 4096 bytes, they accept larger payloads as long as they don't exceed 4096 characters (i.e. you can send a 4096 characters string that contains characters encoded into more than one byte, so the length of the payload in bytes will exceed 4096).

Comment: this is great news - so I can send a single request for as many registration IDs that I want ? or is there a limit to that ?

Comment: @epeleg The limit is 1000 registration IDs.

Answer (score 0):

But as of today it allowed till 4089 characters to be sent via GCM and 511 characters were visible in the notification panel when its slide down.
*Have practically tested it*