# How much data we can send through push notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

How much(size) amount of data we can pass through push notifications.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The payload limit is 4Kb for Android phones, or 2Kb for iOS. See [the reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) for more information.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The [table of error codes for GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) provides an answer to your question. Specifically, have a look at `error:MessageTooBig`:

> **Message Too Big (HTTP code 200 + error:MessageTooBig)**
>   Check that the total size of the payload data included in a message does not exceed GCM limits: 4096 bytes for most messages, or 2048 bytes in the case of messages to topics or notification messages on iOS. This includes both the keys and the values.

The limit appears [somewhat flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698621/how-to-count-android-gcm-payload-length) and [doesn't include registration ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699947/does-the-payload-4096-bytes-include-the-registration-id-length) or any of the predefined parameters.